# VS2015 inconsistent compiler behavior

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

I have encountered the following VS2015 CTP6 VC++ compiler behavior:

```
unsigned char a = 1;

unsigned char x = (2 | a);   //this compiles fine

unsigned char y[] = {2 | a}; //this emits warning C4838: conversion from
                             //'int' to 'unsigned char' requires a narrowing conversion
```

I assume that some implicit type conversion or promotion occurs in the definition of `y`, but whatever is happening there should've happened in the line that defines `x` as well - yet this line compiles fine.

Reversing the operands order didn't help, casting `2` to `unsigned char` didn't help either:

```
unsigned char y[] = {(unsigned char)2 | a}; //same warning
unsigned char y[] = {a | 2};                //same warning
```

Same thing happens with other bitwise operators as well. The only thing that resolved the warning was an explicit cast of the result of bitwise operation: `unsigned char y[] = {(unsigned char)(2 | a)};`

Can anyone explain such compiler behavior? Is it a bug?

**Edit**:

`GCC 4.9.1` compiles cleanly, `Clang 3.5` issues an error: "*error: non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'int' to 'unsigned char' in initializer list [-Wc++11-narrowing]*". Can anyone explain?

Comment: Before you accuse a compiler of having a bug, it's good to try on several other popular modern compilers.  For example, rextester.com would let you easily try that code on both gcc and clang, with no need to install them on your own computer.

Comment: How is a warning a bug? A compiler is pretty free to issue them on perfectly good code, or silently accept dubious code.

Comment: I think bug's the wrong word, but I'm curious as to the logic. This compiles with no warnings on VS2013.

Comment: @BenVoigt It was a question, not an accusation. And since the compiler isn't in a release version, I think it's not a long shot to assume it has problems... Anyway, I followed your suggestion and got some interesting results. GCC 4.9.1 compiles cleanly, Clang 3.5 issues an error: "*error: non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'int' to 'unsigned char' in initializer list [-Wc++11-narrowing]*". Can anyone explain?

Comment: @MSalters Still there should be a valid explanation for the warning

Comment: Well, there *is* an explanation right there in the message. "Narrowing conversions" are known risky.

Comment: @MSalters Ok, so why the same doesn't apply for initialization of `x`? Moreover, why in `Clang` it's an error, not warning? Error must be backed up by a standard. Also, why this fails as well: `unsigned char y[] = {(unsigned char)2 | a};`? Why we still have a promotion to `int` here?

Comment: @icepack: That's in the clang error too.  "in initialization list".  `y` has an initialization list, `x` doesn't.  You have a promotion in `(unsigned char)2 | a` because the `|` operator causes the usual promotions.  This is not conversion of one operand to the type of the other, this is promotion.

Comment: @BenVoigt You mean there is a promotion of the *result* of operation `|` to `int` ?

Comment: @icepack the operands of `|` are promoted to `int` if they are narrower integral types, which `unsigned char` is. Same with `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `%`, `&`, etc.

Comment: The workaround you are looking for is `unsigned char y[] = { (unsigned char)(2|a) };` which is pretty ugly, so I guess you could look for another way to do what you're trying to do

Comment: @MattMcNabb Yes, I'm aware of the workaround. What's a bit not clear to me is when the promotion occurs and whether it's mandatory or optional. Is it correct that the promotion occurs when the operands are being evaluated for the operation, i.e. after casting (so the casting has no effect)? Also, I read that the the promotion *may* occur, but not mandatory: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rules for aggregate initialization changed between C++03 and today -- a lot.  (All quotes from section `[dcl.init.aggr]` which remains 8.5.1 in all versions)

In C++03, the rule was

> All implicit type conversions are considered when initializing the aggregate member with an initializer from an initializer-list.

In draft n3485 (roughly, C++11) and n4296 (roughly, C++14), this case is now covered by a different rule

> When an aggregate is initialized by an initializer list, as speciﬁed in 8.5.4, the elements of the initializer list are taken as initializers for the members of the aggregate, in increasing subscript or member order. Each
>   member is copy-initialized from the corresponding initializer-clause. **If the initializer-clause is an expression and a narrowing conversion is required to convert the expression, the program is ill-formed.**

This was an intentional breakage of backward compatibility, and listed as such in the C++11 appendix:

> - Change: Narrowing restrictions in aggregate initializers
> - Rationale: Catches bugs.
> - Effect on original feature: **Valid C++ 2003 code may fail to compile in this International Standard.** For example, the following code is valid in C++ 2003 but invalid in this International Standard because `double` to `int` is a narrowing conversion:
>
>   ```
>   int x[] = { 2.0 };
>   ```

The semantics of promotion which cause OR-ing `unsigned char` values to yield a result that doesn't fit back into `unsigned char` without narrowing have already been fully explained here:

- [Are the "usual arithmetic conversions" and the "integer promotions" the same thing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28142902/103167)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that explains a lot. What I still miss here is a clear definition of when the promotion occurs and whether it's a must (once it happened, the rest is clear according to the quotes that you added).

Comment: @icepack: That should be a separate question, IMO.  Do you need help looking for an existing one?

Comment: @icepack: I think this is the question you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28142902/103167  I'll link it from my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the link. According to the quote inside, there shouldn't be any arithmetic promotion in case of 2 operands of the same type, like in this case: `unsigned char y[] = {(unsigned char)2 | a};` So the only promotion here is an integral one and the standard is kind of vague here: "*A prvalue of an integer type other than bool, char16_t, char32_t, or wchar_t whose integer conversion
rank (4.13) is less than the rank of int can be converted to a prvalue of type int*". The wording is not decisive, just "can"...

Comment: @icepack: The wording is a bit weird.  First "these conversions CAN be done".  Then "this set of conversions form the *integral promotions*", meaning that if said conversion isn't done (which the *can* wording allows), then no integral promotion has been done.  Finally, the bold portion in the linked answer, which says "integral promotions SHALL be performed", which rules out exercising the permission not to do them which the word *can* gave.

Comment: Great! That probably was the original meaning, but as usual with C++ they've managed to define it as complex as possible :)

Answer (score 2):

`(2 | a)` is of type `int`, because 2 is an int, and `a`gets promoted.

C++ inherited from C an ability to silently perform unsafe conversions from a wider type to a smaller type - unsafe in the sense that any higher order bits are lost.

That's what this does:

```
unsigned char x = (2 | a);
```

The new brace initialisation syntax is an opportunity to ditch this backward compatibility. By design, if you want an unsafe/lossy conversion when using brace initialisation you must ask for it. That's why this doesn't work:

```
unsigned char y[] = {2 | a};
```

Initialising an `unsigned char` from `int` loses information so needs a cast.

This isn't a bug, it's required behaviour. And one day it will catch a bug at compile time that would have taken you hours to find when it happened at run time, so always use the new syntax when you can.

Comment: 1. This doesn't work either: `unsigned char y[] = {(unsigned char)2 | a};`. 2. I think you're confusing the new brace init syntax with the old array initialization syntax (`y` is an array).

Comment: @icepack: The | operator performs integer promotions (like almost all binary operators) so it will always return an integer type at least as wide as an int, even if you write `(char)2 | (char)a`. You need to cast the *result* of the |

Comment: @rici That's not the question. What's not clear is why this conversion seemlesly converts back to a narrower type for a variable initialization but not for an array initialization

Comment: @icepack: the array is irrelevant. You should get the same warning with `unsigned char x = { 2 | a };`. As alan says, it' the use of an initialization list.

Comment: One thing wrong with this answer -- in the array case, brace initialization syntax is not new, and backward compatibility is a concern.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure about Alan's answer because the brace syntax to initialize an array (which is what you're doing there) is valid C syntax, so that's not new to C++.

On VS2013, your code compiles for me with no warnings. I said something else originally, but as I think about it I'm not sure what's proper as far as issuing warnings go.

Comment: Yes, this warning appeared for me as well in a code that worked perfectly fine in VS2013 :)