# Type Casting In Arithmetic Expressions C++

Tags: c++

```
    int a = 5 , b = 2 ;
    double ans1 = a / b ; // ans1 = 2
    cout << setprecision ( 4 ) << fixed << ans1 << endl ;

    unsigned short int c = USHRT_MAX , d = USHRT_MAX ;
    unsigned int ans2 = c + d ; // ans2 = 131070 
    cout << ans2 ;
```

What happens when the  ( a / b ) is evaluated?

1) the result first stored in int ( variable type on the R.H.S ) and then converted into 64-bit double ( variable type on the L.H.S ) and then stored in the ans1 or first variables are converted into 64-bit double ( variable type on the L.H.S ) and then / takes place ?

2) if first evaluated as the variables type on R.H.S , then how the second one prints the correct ans ( because the ans is out of unsigned short int's limit  )

Answer (score 5):

In the first example, you first divide the two `int`s with truncating integer division and then assign the result of that (2) to `ans1`.

The second case is different in a subtle way: You chose integer types that are *smaller* than `int`. Thus, *before* any arithmetic operator acts on them, they both get converted to `int` (if that fits, as it does here, to `unsigned int` otherwise) while preserving their values, and on `int` the operation you showed does not overflow. Then you assign the result (which has type `int`) to the `unsigned int`, and since it is non-negative, nothing strange happens.

If you tried the second example with `unsigned int` instead of `unsigned short`, you could observe the "integer overflow" (which is no real overflow because unsigned arithmetic wraps).

Comment: As in second case unsigned short int are smaller than int hence they both get converted to int , then in the first case also int is smaller than double , so why not same rule of casting ? Or it is just for ( / ) operator ( special case ) ? .

Comment: #include <iostream>
using namespace std ;
int main()
{
    int a = 1000000 , b = 1000000 ;
    long long int ans = a * b ;
    cout << ans << " " << a << " " << b << endl ;
    long long int c = 1000000 , d = 1000000 ;
    long long int ans2 = c * d ;
    cout << ans2 << " " << c << " " << d ;
    return 0;
}                   // then what about this ? int is smaller then long long int , but first cout prints wrong , but second one correct

Comment: @knock_out This is controlled by a kind of complex set of rules, the so called "usual arithmetic conversions". They are for example explained [here](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-/Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-7-of-n), starting around 19:20 if you don't care about the rest of the talk, or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28142965/3002139) if you only need the wording without explanation.