# gcc 7.2: warning: left shift count >= width of type

Tags: c, gcc

Even though I cast every right operand to `unsigned long long`, the warning persists. Shouldn't `uint8_t << uint64_t` have an implicit cast like this: `(uint64_t) uint8_t << uint64_t`?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31744340/8590292) suggests that I can promote either of the operands and the whole expression will cast to `unsigned long long`, but it might be wrong.

```
bool dgBioReadU64LE(DgBioFile *file, uint64_t *x) {
    uint8_t u[8];
    if (!dgBioReadU8v(file, LEN(u), u)) return false;
    *x = u[0]|(u[1]<<8ULL)|(u[2]<<16ULL)|(u[3]<<24ULL)|(u[4]<<32ULL)|(u[5]<<40ULL)|(u[6]<<48ULL)|(u[7]<<56ULL);
    return true;
}

bool dgBioReadU64BE(DgBioFile *file, uint64_t *x) {
    uint8_t u[8];
    if (!dgBioReadU8v(file, LEN(u), u)) return false;
    *x = u[7]|(u[6]<<8ULL)|(u[5]<<16ULL)|(u[4]<<24ULL)|(u[3]<<32ULL)|(u[2]<<40ULL)|(u[1]<<48ULL)|(u[0]<<56ULL);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Shouldn't `uint8_t << uint64_t` have an implicit cast like this: `(uint64_t) uint8_t << uint64_t`?

**TL;DR** - No, shift operators are special.

**Full answer**

The behaviour you're describing (essentially, matching operand types) is known as the [*usual arithmetic conversions*](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.8) in the C standard.<sup>1</sup>

We see that the standard mandates this for many operators (e.g. for additive operators):

> [**[6.5.6]**](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.6p4) If both operands have arithmetic type, the usual arithmetic conversions are performed on them.

However, we see no such phrase in the equivalent section for bitwise shift operators.  The closest we have is:

> [**[6.5.7]**](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.7p3) The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The type of the result is that of the promoted left operand.

However, the [*integer promotions*](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.1p2) are [a different thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28142902/are-the-usual-arithmetic-conversions-and-the-integer-promotions-the-same-thi) - they say (essentially) that any type smaller than `[unsigned] int` is converted to an `[unsigned] int`.

So the compiler is correct to warn here.  (And as I'm sure you can guess, the solution is to perform an explicit cast on the left-hand operand ;)

---

<sub>1. For the purposes of this answer, I'm considering C11 (specifically [N1570](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html)) canonical.  The behaviour is the same at least as far back as C99.</sub>

Comment: Why are you using n1548, when [n1570, dated 4 months after, exists](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html)

Comment: @antti - because I was not aware of it ;). I'll update answer when next at keyboard.

Answer (score 4):

> This answer suggests that I can promote either of the operands and the whole expression will cast to unsigned long long, but it might be wrong.

It is.

The standard says:

> 6.5.7 *Bitwise shift operators*
>   The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The type of the result is that of the promoted
>   left operand. If the value of the right operand is negative or is
>   greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the
>   behavior is undefined

Which means that you need to cast the left operand, casting the right one doesn't change anything here.

Answer (score 2):

The answer you linked is misleading. It seems to suggest that you can widen *either* operand and it will trigger automatic conversion of the other operand to the common (wider) type. That is true for most binary operators in C. However, that is not true for shift operators.

The shift operators in C are actually *special* in that regard. They behave asymmetrically. Changing the type of the right operand to a wider type does not trigger the conversion of the left operand to the type of the right operand, and does not affect the resultant type. The resultant type is always defined by the (possibly promoted) type of the left operand.

In your case you specifically have to convert the *left* operand to `unsigned long long` type.

Answer (score 1):

The result of the left and right shift operators has the same type as the left operand.  So the type of the right operand won’t affect the type of the result.

You need to cast the left operand to `unsigned long long` to get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

> Even though I cast every right operand to `unsigned long long`, the
>   warning persists. Shouldn't `uint8_t << uint64_t` have an implicit
>   cast like this: `(uint64_t) uint8_t << uint64_t`?

No.

> This answer suggests that I can promote either of the operands and the
>   whole expression will cast to `unsigned long long`, but it might be
>   wrong.

I see why you think the linked answer says that, but it demonstrates using a constant of type `unsigned long long` as the *left* operand.  That part is correct.  To the extent that the answer suggests that the same could have been achieved by using a wider type on the right, it is misleading.

The standard specifies:

> The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The type
>   of the result is that of the promoted left operand. If the value of
>   the right operand is negative or is greater than or equal to the width
>   of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined.

([C2011, 6.5.7/3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.7p3))

Note well that the type of the result expression is determined by the type of the left operand only, and that it is the *value* of the right operand relative to the (promoted) type of the left operand that can trigger this particular undefinedness provision.

You are left-shifting a `uint8_t`.  The integer promotions will be performed on the left operand, resulting in a value of type `int`.  Supposing that your `int`s are 32 bits wide, the left shifts by 32 or more bits produce undefined behavior, and in some cases you might get additional undefined behavior arising from the fact that it is *signed*, not unsigned int.

Correct this by casting the *left* operand.  For example, `(uint64_t) u[7] << 56`.