# What's the type of an expression with two operandes of the same size?

Tags: c, expression

It is known that if you have an expression of two operands, the type of the computed value will be the larger (in bytes) type of them with integers or the one with the best precision if there's a real.

For example :

```
( 1   +   2L )  =  3L
 int  +  long   =  long

( 1L   +   1.0 )  =  1.0
 long  +  double  =  double
```

---

But if you have :

```
(signed int + unsigned int)
```

or

```
(wchar_t + short)
```

- How does the compiler decide ?

Comment: Your "it is known" assumption isn't always true. For example, `short` + `short` = `int`.

Comment: Hum.. yes you talk about integer promotions ?

Comment: Like this: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.8

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28142902/are-the-usual-arithmetic-conversions-and-the-integer-promotions-the-same-thi

Comment: Integers that are signed get promoted to unsigned integers, but the result might not be in range. Better is not to mix types. If you have to, convert them to a larger type than will hold the input and ouput values, and then test if it will fit the target type, which you have not mentioned.

Comment: Please read [Lundin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46073296/918959) in  the duplicate. In particular from it it will follow that `signed int + unsigned int` has type `unsigned int`, and `wchar_t + short` is either of type `signed int` or `unsigned int` depending on the bitness of these types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From Here](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter2/expressions_and_arithmetic.html)

2.8.1.2. Signed and unsigned integers
A lot of conversions between different types of integers are caused by mixing the various flavours of integers in expressions. Whenever these happen, the integral promotions will already have been done. For all of them, if the new type can hold all of the values of the old type, then the value remains unchanged.

When converting from a signed integer to an unsigned integer whose length is equal to or longer than the original type, then if the signed value was nonnegative, its value is unchanged. If the value was negative, then it is converted to the signed form of the longer type and then made unsigned by conceptually adding it to one greater than the maximum that can be held in the unsigned type. In a twos complement system, this preserves the original bit-pattern for positive numbers and guarantees ‘sign-extension’ of negative numbers.

Whenever an integer is converted into a shorter unsigned type, there can be no ‘overflow’, so the result is defined to be ‘the non-negative remainder on division by the number one greater than the largest unsigned number that can be represented in the shorter type’. That simply means that in a two's complement environment the low-order bits are copied into the destination and the high-order ones discarded.

Converting an integer to a shorter signed type runs into trouble if there is not enough room to hold the value. In that case, the result is implementation defined (although most old-timers would expect that simply the low-order bit pattern is copied).

That last item could be a bit worrying if you remember the integral promotions, because you might interpret it as follows—if I assign a char to another char, then the one on the right is first promoted to one of the kinds of int; could doing the assignment result in converting (say) an int to a char and provoking the ‘implementation defined’ clause? The answer is no, because assignment is specified not to involve the integral promotions, so you are safe.

Comment: This really doesn't even answer the question. It does talk about integer conversions superficially but not even about the *usual arithmetic conversions* that the OP asks about.