# typecasting long to int and short in C

Tags: c, casting, typecasting-operator

```
long x = <some value>
int y = <some value>
```

I want to subtract y from x , which of the following will give me different or same results

```
 x = (int)x - y;

 x = x-y

 x = short(x) - short(y)
```

Comment: It depends on the values of x and y and if they exceed the range of short or int. Did you try it?

Comment: Before you cast, you must make sure the `long` will fit in `int` (e.g. check against `INT_MIN/INT_MAX`) and the same for `short`. (e.g. `SHRT_MIN/SHRT_MAX`)

Comment: What is `short(x)` ? Did you mean `(short)x` ? Anyway - why don't you just give it a try? If you don't understand what you see then you can ask here.

Comment: You could try these numbers `    x=5234000000L;
    y = 100;
`

Comment: or read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28142965/4386427

Comment: See [Implicit type promotion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules).

Answer (score 0):

The type `long` is "bigger" than `int`. Smaller types can be *automatically* casted to bigger types. So, this code:

```c
someLongNumber + someIntNumber
```

is basically equal to

```c
someLongNumber + (long)someIntNumber
```

So the output will be `long`. You don't have to cast if you want to place the result in `x`. However, if you want to place it in `y`, you must cast the `x` operand to `int` (`(int)x`), or the whole operation (`(int)(x - y)`).

Comment: Nitpick: the Standard guarantees that a `long` has greater _rank_ than an `int`, but both may be the same size (the only guarantee is that a `long` is at least as wide as an `int`), and on 32 bit Windows platforms `long` and `int` are in fact the same size. Also, what you are calling an "automatic cast" isn't really a cast, but is referred to in the Standard as an _implicit conversion_.

Comment: Please, consider adding a note about the possible overflows.